# Как ускорить сборку проекта под Win64 - Embarcadero C++Builder 10.2.3?

Tags: embarcadero

Если делать сборку проекта под Win32 - уходит времени 0м. 57 сек.. Сборка под Win64 с теме же параметрами, настройками, железом, ОС и т.д. занимает 2 мин. 58 сек.... Причина не понятна.

Подскажите может где-то в настройках проекта или в настройках IDE есть возможность, как то этот процесс ускорить?

Спасибо!

Comment: А по времени это сколько будет? Например, у меня диплом (с++/Qt) на ноуте (win7, 2 ядра + 2 гига оперативы + hdd) собирался 15 минут и это было много. А вот на компе (win7, характеристики уже не вспомню) занимало минуту. И это только из-за разницы в железе

Comment: указал в процентном соотношение.

Comment: Вот поэтому я и спросил про численные значения :)

Comment: исправил вопрос. указал время сборки. убрал проценты.

Comment: Мне с моим дипломом помогло ускорение сборки разделением проекта на библиотеки, тогда вместо включения исходного кода собрались отдельно

Comment: идея хорошая. но не понятна причина. есть предположение, что для bcc нужно какой то флаг дергнуть. не знаю. пока рецепта в сети не нашел.